# post request Property 'post' does not exist on type '(optionalToken?: string | undefined) => AxiosInstance'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, post

```
const addUserSeviceExpertHours = async () => {
        await fetchClient
            .post(API.ADD_USERSERVICE_EXPERT_HOURS, {
                ProducId: cartData?.productID,
                Amount: (limitExceedHours * cartData.unitRate + tax).toFixed(2),
                Hours: limitExceedHours,
                ProductDescription: 'expert-hour',
            })
            .then()
            .then((response: any) => response)
            .catch((response: Error) => {
                return response;
            });
    };
```

I'm trying to call this POST api but it is not working. On POST it is giving the error

Property 'post' does not exist on type '(optionalToken?: string | undefined) => AxiosInstance'

Comment: What is `fetchClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Going by your post, the type signature for `fetchClient` is `(optionalToken?: string | undefined) => AxiosInstance`. This is a function signature and that means you almost certainly want to *call* `fetchClient()` in order to retrieve the object of type `AxiosInstance` that it will return.